# How to know if a user associated with a process is active

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi

I use `GetPixel` to get colors of some points of `Program Manager` (desktop), however if the system is switched to another user, `GetPixel` always returns `white`.

So I need to know whether the user is active or the system is switched to another user.

A solution should work for OS: Windows XP till Windows 8.

This is what I do:

```
HWND ProgmanHwnd = FindWindow(L"Progman", L"Program Manager");
if (!ProgmanHwnd) return;
HDC hDC = GetWindowDC(ProgmanHwnd);
if (!hDC) return;
COLORREF color = GetPixel(hDC, 10, 10); // it's always white when a used is logged off
```

Comment: So rather than "whether the user is logged on" it's more of a matter of "whether that process's Desktop (or Window Station, I never understood what was what on this subject) is visible"?

Comment: @Medinoc Probably, yes, but `IsWindowVisible` always returns `true` for the Program Manager.

Comment: I think `IsWindowVisible` is says whether a window is visible *on its desktop*, but is completely independent of whether the desktop itself is visible.

Comment: @Medinoc But `Program manager` is the Desktop. It displays a wallpaper. Do you know any way to get to know that the Desktop is visible? It is always visible when a used is logged in. That's why my question is about it.

Comment: @Ezee: Program Manager is a shell process running on the `WinSta0\Desktop` desktop of *a particular interactive workstation*.  There can be multiple worstations/desktops running at a time if multiple users are logged in, whether that is via Fast User Switching, Terminal Services, or Remote Desktop Connection.

Comment: Try to use [WTSEnumerateSessionsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee621014(v=vs.85).aspx). Returned structures have helpful fields `State` and `pUserName`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: YES! That's what I mean! This kind of desktop, not the *desktop window*.

Comment: @Medinoc If you meant this, do you have any ideas how to know that `WinSta0\Desktop` "is visible"?

Comment: `WTSEnumerateSessionsEx` is available since Win7. I tried `WTSEnumerateSessions` but it returns 0, and `GetLastErrors` is also 0. Has anyone used it for a local PC ?

Comment: Yes, I use `WTSEnumerateSessions()` and it works fine. If it returns FALSE, `GetLastError()` cannot return 0, unless you made another system call that wipe `GetLastError()`.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov `WTSEnumerateSessions` doesn't exactly what I asked. Thanks you. Wanna post it as an answer?

Comment: @remy-lebeau Thank you also. There was a bug with the api call. And `GetLastError` returns some value. You was right, I was wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [WTSEnumerateSessionsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee621014(v=vs.85).aspx). Returned structures have helpful fields `State` and `pUserName`.